# jQuery delete text onfocus

Tags: jquery, text

I've been trying to have a default value in a text input, then with jQuery, when you "onfocus" the textbox, it makes the text black (default a light gray), and deletes the default value. I think you know what I'm talking about, so do you know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<input class="txtClass" type="text" defaultVal="Enter your Name" />
<input class="txtClass" type="text" defaultVal="Enter your Designation" />
```

*javascript*

```
$('body').ready(function(){
  $('.txtClass').each( function () {
    $(this).val($(this).attr('defaultVal'));
    $(this).css({color:'grey'});
      });

  $('.txtClass').focus(function(){
    if ( $(this).val() == $(this).attr('defaultVal') ){
      $(this).val('');
      $(this).css({color:'black'});
    }
    });
  $('.txtClass').blur(function(){
    if ( $(this).val() == '' ){
      $(this).val($(this).attr('defaultVal'));
      $(this).css({color:'grey'});
    }
    });
});
```

**See working example:** <strike>http://jsbin.com/ovida3</strike>
http://jsbin.com/ovida3/2

Answer (score 2):

The [jquery watermark plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/) allows you to achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input:text').bind({
    focus: function () {
        var self = $(this);

        if (self.val() == self.attr('defaultValue')) {
            self.val('').removeClass('default');
        };
    },
    blur: function () {
        var self = $(this),
            val = jQuery.trim(self.val());

        if (val == "" || val == self.attr('defaultValue')) {
          self.val(self.attr('defaultValue')).addClass('default');  
        };
    }
}).trigger('blur');
```

Have a CSS class of `default` which sets the text color to whatever you desire.

**Example Usage: http://www.jsfiddle.net/2S9hW/**

​

Answer (score 1):

What I'm currently using for inputs taking City Values. On focus it removes the value. On blur (unfocused) it returns the default value but informs the user it is required.

#### css

```
`.red{color:red;}​`
```

#### html

```
<input type="text" class="city" value="City" id="oCity" name="oCity"></input>
<label class="oCity red"></label>
<input type="text" class="city" value="City" id="dCity" name="dCity">
<label class="dCity red"></label>​
<input type="text" class="city" value="City" id="dCity" name="dCity">
<label class="dCity red"></label>​
```

#### jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var defaultVal = 'City';
$('.city').focus(function() {
    $(this).val('');
});
 $('.city').blur(function(){
    var Value = $(this).val();
    var oId = $(this).attr('id');
    if(Value == '')
    {
        $(this).val(defaultVal);
        $('.'+oId).text('Required');
    }           
});
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Your basiclly creating what the placeholder attribute of the HTML5 text element supports. So you should just use the placeholder attribute and then check if the browser supports the placeholder functionality:

```
function supports_input_placeholder() {
    var i = document.createElement('input');
    return 'placeholder' in i;
}
if (!support_input_placeholder()) {
    $(':text').focus(function(){
        var self = $(this);
        if (self.val() == self.attr('placeholder')) {
            self.val('');
        }
    }).blur(function(){
        var self = $(this),
            value = $.trim(self.val());
        if(val == '') {
            self.val(self.attr('placeholder');
        }
    });
}

<input type="text" name="desc" placeholder="My Email Account">
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can also use Google Watermark plugin, this way:**

Download the latest jQuery script:

http://jquery.com/download/

Download the Watermark plugin:

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/

**========== head  ==========**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.watermark.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function () {
        $("#input-name").watermark("Your name");
        $("#input-email").watermark("Your e-mail address");
    });
});
</script>
```

**========== body  ==========**

```
<div id="wrap-contact">
<form id="form-contact" name="form-contact" method="post" action="">
<div id="layer-email">
<input type="text" name="input-email" id="input-email" />
</div>
<div id="layer-name">
<input type="text" name="input-name" id="input-name" />
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

**========== CSS  ==========**

```
/*
========================
form styles
========================
*/
#wrap-contact {
    margin: auto;
    width: 760px;
}
#layer-email {
    float:left;
    width:340px;
    padding:2px;
    background:#ccc url(images/user.png) no-repeat 98% 50%;
}
#layer-name {
    float:right;
    width:340px;
    padding:2px;
    background:#ccc url(images/email.png) no-repeat 98% 50%;
}
#input-email {
    width: 260px;
    font: 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    padding: 4px;

}
#input-name {
    width: 260px;
    font: 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    padding: 4px;
}

/*
========================
watermark styles
========================
*/
.watermark {color: #999 !important;}
```